# How do I fix the default version of PHP after uninstalling PHP OSX?

Tags: macos, php, apache-http-server, php5

I installed [PHP OSX](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) because I wanted to test some PHP 5.5 code on the command-line/interactive shell. On my local web server, I started receiving errors in functional code from before I installed PHP OSX. I then decided to uninstall PHP OSX and followed the instructions on its webpage.

1. There was no line `LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so` in my `httpd.conf`.
2. I uncommented the line `LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` in my `httpd.conf`.
3. `sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf` and `sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/other/+entropy-php.conf`.
4. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/php5-*` and `sudo rm /usr/local/php5`.
5. `sudo apachectl restart`

PHP is displaying as plaintext on my web server. How do I fix this?

`httpd` says that PHP5 is loaded:

```
sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
  ... (static)
  php5_module (shared)
  ... (shared)
```

Comment: do you access the files through the http address or files:/// ?

Comment: I use http://localhost/~nobleuplift/index.php

Answer (score 0):

My `/private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf` had entries for mod_php5.c. Once I replaced it with the OS X entries, it worked:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```